# Is it possible to create a generic type T[A <: C[U], B <: C[U], U] that can be used as T[A, B]?

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following case class:

```
case class <*>[Q <: Quantity[T], R <: Quantity[T], T](value: T) 
  extends Quantity[T]
```

I would like to use it as such:

```
type Area[T] = Length[T] <*> Length[T]
```

However, I get an error saying that `<*>` expects three parameters and I’ve given only two. I would like it to work like this:

```
type Area[T] = <*>[Length[T], Length[T], T]
```

I tried the following but it gave me an error:

```
trait Quantity[T] {
  type Value = T

  def value: T
}

case class <*>[Q <: Quantity[_],
               R <: Quantity[_]](value: Q#Value)
                                (implicit eq: Q#Value =:= R#Value)
  extends Quantity[Q#Value]
```

> Error:(13, 110) illegal inheritance;
>   self-type `<*>[Q,R]` does not conform to `Quantity[_$1]`'s selftype `Quantity[_$1]`
>
> ```
> case class <*>[Q <: Quantity[_],
>                R <: Quantity[_]](value: Q#Value)
>                                 (implicit eq: Q#Value =:= R#Value)
>   extends Quantity[Q#Value]
>   ^
> ```

Is there a workaround for this? I don’t mind renaming the case classes if necessary, although I do want the nice infix syntax.

Comment: @Kigyo it would not compile. type T will be still unknown

Comment: @wedens You are right. I must have entered something different in the repl. Thanks.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but isn't the problem that the first Quantity[_] and the second one are considered as different types(with the same placeholder name _$1 used in "different scopes") ? I think I've had that happen to me some times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Q#Value` reference.

I'd suggest using an implicit to enforce your type constraints rather than trying to make existentials work:

```
sealed trait CanStar[Q, R]
// could include =:=-like values in CanStar if you like
object CanStar {
  implicit def canStar[Q <: Quantity[T], R <: Quantity[T], T] =
    new CanStar[Q, R]{}
}

sealed case class <*>[Q,R](value: Q)(implicit cs: CanStar[Q, R])
```

Then `<*>` is a two-parameter type as desired, but you can only ever instantiate `Q <*> R` with `Q` and `R` which are suitably related (because implicit `CanStar[Q, R]`s are only available for suitable `Q` and `R`).

Comment: The problem is that `value` must be of type `T`, not of type `Q`.

Comment: In that case `value: Any`, and `cs: CanStar[Q, R, value.type]` ?